Google lighthouse report complains about deprecated PayPal SDK javascript
We've recently run Google lighthouse for one of our sites and noticed that it is complaining about a deprecated API, namely PayPal's SDK JS which we use to display their payment buttons.

I probably haven't had enough coffee today but I can't see an updated version / URL of this javascript file and we're not hosting it locally, instead getting it directly from source.
https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?currency=GBP&commit=false&components=messages,buttons,funding-eligibility&enable-funding=paylater&disable-funding=card,credit&client-id=xxx

Any suggestions as to what we're doing wrong or is it a false positive? I feel I'm missing something really obvious!
Edit : Google are warning that the deprecated JS (unloadhandler) will be prevented from running by the end of Q1 2025.


It complains about the SDK using an UnloadHandler, so most likely this is referring to https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/deprecating-unload The people at PayPal are in charge of handling this, not you.

@C3roe - indeed it does and I'm aware that the PayPal dev team should change it, not us. Deprecation has been warned for some time though so I would have though they'd have had it updated by now.

I would assume that PayPal themselves have enough of an interest to keep this working, that they will implement the necessary workarounds / new approaches in due time. Or maybe what they are using it for isn't really essential, and they included enough safeguards around it, so that the script won't break once this actually gets removed from browsers.
